# Is there a way to automatically update an installed NuGet package in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

As the title says, I'd like to know if there is a way to automatically update an installed NuGet package as soon as a new version becomes available in the package source.

The use case is a package that applies certain company policies (code analysis, signing, ...) to our projects, and as soon as this package is updated, I'd like to be able to configure an automatic update for this package.

I do know that there is a package restore feature for NuGet which will automatically download the missing packages when the project is built, but does this download a specific version or the most recent package with a matching name?

Comment: How did you end up implementing this?

Comment: @ShervinShahrdar As described in my own answer below, there is no way to automatically update an installed package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NuGet` package restore feature intentionally only works for one specific version. The same package with a different version number will not be used if the package with a lower version is missing.

Example 1

- packages.config references 1.0.0.**0**
- package source contains 1.0.0.**0** and 1.0.0.**1**
- 1.0.0.**0** is the version that will automatically be restored

Example 2

- packages.config references 1.0.0.**0**
- package source contains only 1.0.0.**1**
- no automatic restore will be performed, the project won't build

This behaviour makes sense as otherwise there is no way to control what you are actually building. Imagine someone updates the package source with a newer version of a package just before you build a release that will get shipped...

Comment: "otherwise there is no way to control what you are actually building."  Actually, you can always lock a nuget package to a specific version.

Comment: And since you can lock a nuget package to a specific version, that makes it particularly unfortunate that nuget always selects the earliest version in a specified range of versions.  That means you don't get bug fixes in dependencies unless you take the time to manually check for new package versions and you modify your project files to rule out versions you know to be bad.

Answer (score 2):

Although coming late to the party, I would like to add, that updating NuGet packages may be possible with PackageReference.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/nuget/reference/package-versioning.